# Is there any alternate way to processing DICOM images using WPF in C# without any third party/Library?

Tags: c#, wpf, dicom

I started working in a new project with a big challenge. I am working in a medical project and in that I have to read DICOM images and process the image with its properties. I gathered some basic knowledge on DICOM and PACS. As I worked on WPF around 2 years of my career so I choose to do this project using C# and WPF. I googled a lot and even I went through many articles in SO and also in codeproject, every where I found they used some libraries/ third party tools like:

**gdcm** , **LEADTOOLS** , **ClearCanvas**

Can any body suggest me any alternate way of doing DICOM Image processing without using any third party/library or is it impossible without using libraries/third party ?

I have gone through [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287127/net-dicom-libraries) for choose a best suitable library for DICOM image processing, but looking for an alternate way to solving this.Please feel free to suggest which is the best and more flexible library from the above list only if there is not any alternate way to achieve the task.

Any idea, link, suggestion or any initiation will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious why you don't want to use a 3rd party library?

Comment: I am curious to learn the things happening and other thing is I am scaring about flexibility in use of third party according to my need. As you know apart of this there are many things to look after before use of third party/ library like(Code Safe, Handling events/properties etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In one way or another the third-party libraries are also created from scratch, so of course it is possible to create a DICOM image processing solution without relying on any third-party libraries. Using whole or parts of an open-source library will most certainly take you to a functional solution in considerably shorter time, though.

One third-party library that is mentioned in the link you are referring to is [mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm). This is a relatively light-weight open-source library with support for WPF (and Silverlight). If you want to, I am pretty sure you should be able to extract those parts from this library that are relevant to your project.

Another light-weight library is [Evil DICOM](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/). I am not completely sure that this library has very much image processing functionality, though.

**UPDATE MAY 31: SUMMARY OF DISCUSSION**

[mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm) is an open-source library under the LGPL license. An example of image rendering usage is given in the SL.DicomToXml (Silverlight) application, equally applicable to WPF applications. In the [code-behind of the MainPage](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm/blob/master/SL.DicomToXml/MainPage.xaml.cs), `fileNameButton_Click` method, there is code to demonstrate DICOM image file loading and rendering.

There is currently no up-to-date binary distribution of mdcm available, but it should be fairly easy to build required libraries from the solution in the [mdcm](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm) repository. Source code can either be obtained using a [Git](http://git-scm.com/) client or by downloading the latest revision by clicking on the **ZIP** button on the repository home page.

If you need to get more acquainted with DICOM image processing details, it is probably good to start by having a look at the DICOM Standard itself, and also to parse a DICOM image file to get the feeling for what information it contains. A good starting point is the [official DICOM homepage](http://medical.nema.org/). A quick introduction with links to software is given [here](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/dicom/index.html). There is also a general, more lengthy tutorial available [here](http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.se/).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But I am not aware of all the properties of DICOM image and again I have to learn the use of the third-party libraries and need to purchase it(the third-party libraries) again

Comment: Can you please share any sample/demo application which uses **mdcm** third-Party library with the third party library **dlls** if you have ?

Comment: mdcm is an open-source library under the LGPL license, so you are free to use it at no cost in your application as long as you adhere to LGPL. When it comes to usage examples, please have a look at the SL.DicomToXml (Silverlight) application in the mdcm repository (actually developed by me as part of SL migration of mdcm). In the [code-behind of the MainPage](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm/blob/master/SL.DicomToXml/MainPage.xaml.cs), fileNameButton_Click method, you can see how a DICOM file is loaded and how the image can be rendered. Hopefully you can go from there to explore the library further

Comment: How will I get the library dll, Can I get your code access for getting idea on handling **mdcm** third-Party library?

Comment: With mdcm, you will need to build the DLL yourself. There is no up-to-date binary distribution of the library publicly available that I know of.

Comment: How will I get mdcm ? from the same link what you posted above ?
If yes then I am not able to download it, kindly provide me the exact link from where I can download the mdcm files and directions of using it too.

Comment: On the [repository website](https://github.com/rcd/mdcm), there is a **ZIP** button fairly high up to the left. Click this button to download the latest revision of the code. You will need a regular version of Visual Studio to build it (not Express), since it contains codecs for JPEG compressed images etc. written in C.

Comment: Do not mind please, one last question still I want to learn about developing my own library which will take care of dealing DICOM images processing. Because every time whenever I'll try to implement/enhance my application I need to dig into the third party library whose code is unknown to me completely. Apart of this for extra features I need to wait for the next version of the third party library which I do not want. So kindly suggest me any good link for acquiring complete knowledge on processing DICOM images.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some additional links. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Anders, during reading image I am getting exception from https://github.com/rcd/mdcm/blob/master/Dicom/Codec/DicomCodec.cs" in IDcmCodec GetCodec(DicomTransferSyntax ts)

Comment: can u please tell me where I made the mistake?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain, I suggest that you post your issue in the [mdcm Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mdcm). Please provide more detailed information about the exception you get in that post.